# How to make SBT/Play look in directory for sbt-plugins.jar?

Tags: playframework, sbt

Just picked up a Scala/Play project at work and am trying to understand the whay SBT works after having worked with Apache Maven.

The Typesafe and Sonatype repos have recently become blocked at work and when I run the build, it complains about missing plugin jars. It seems that SBT is ALWAYS trying ONLY online repos, even though I have additional repositories specified in the `plugins.sbt` file as below:

```
[warn]  [NOT FOUND  ] play#sbt-plugin;2.1.1!sbt-plugin.jar (22ms)
[warn] ==== typesafe-ivy-releases: tried
```

I do see this jar present in the local play repo (under `%PLAY_HOME%/repositories/local`) and I do see `local` specified in Play's global `sbt.boot.properites` and `play.boot.properties` files.

How can I get SBT to actually look there (after looking at other, online sources)?

I've also added the following to the Play and SBT `boot.properties` files, hoping to point it explicitly, but it didn't help:

```
play-local: file://${play.home}/../repository/local/, [organization]/[module]/[revision]/[type]s/[artifact](-[classifier]).[ext]
```

At this point I'm stumped.  I expect to at least see a *local: tried* message at build time.

Is there a way to make SBT look locally for `sbt-plugins.jar`?  Is there some kind of caching going on?  Am I missing something? Please advise.

**EDIT1 (3/12/2014): as requested, here's my plugins.sbt file (local, project level)**

```
import sbt._
import Defaults._

logLevel := Level.Warn

resolvers ++= Seq(
    "Typesafe repository" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/",
    "sonatype-releasess" at "http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/"
)

addSbtPlugin("play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.1.1")

addSbtPlugin("org.scalastyle" % "scalastyle-sbt-plugin" % "0.3.1")

addSbtPlugin("com.github.play2war" % "play2-war-plugin" % "1.0")
```

I also have a root level `sbt.plugins` file (under `%PLAY_HOME%/framework/project`) which looks like this:

```
logLevel := Level.Warn

resolvers += Classpaths.typesafeResolver

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe" % "sbt-mima-plugin" % "0.1.4")

addSbtPlugin( "com.typesafe.sbtscalariform" % "sbtscalariform" % "0.5.1") 

addSbtPlugin("com.github.mpeltonen" % "sbt-idea" % "1.1.0")
```

Here's the stdout of the `play clean` command performed at `projRoot\src\main level`:

```
[info] Loading project definition from C:\path\to\my\proj\src\main
[warn]  [NOT FOUND  ] play#sbt-plugin;2.1.1!sbt-plugin.jar (29ms)
[warn] ==== typesafe-ivy-releases: tried
[warn]   http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/play/sbt-plugin/scala_2.9.2/sbt_0.12/2.1.1/jars/sbt-plugin.jar
[warn]  [NOT FOUND  ] org.scalastyle#scalastyle-sbt-plugin;0.3.1!scalastyle-sbt-plugin.jar (204ms)
[warn] ==== sonatype-releasess: tried
[warn]   http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/org/scalastyle/scalastyle-sbt-plugin_2.9.2_0.12/0.3.1/scalastyle-sbt-plugin-0.3.1.jar
[warn]  [NOT FOUND  ] com.github.play2war#play2-war-plugin;1.0!play2-war-plugin.jar (13ms)
[warn] ==== sbt-plugin-releases: tried
[warn]   http://scalasbt.artifactoryonline.com/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/com.github.play2war/play2-war-plugin/scala_2.9.2/sbt_0.12/1.0/jars/play2-war-plugin.jar
[warn]  [NOT FOUND  ] com.typesafe.sbteclipse#sbteclipse-plugin;2.1.1!sbteclipse-plugin.jar (31ms)
[warn] ==== typesafe-ivy-releases: tried
[warn]   http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/com.typesafe.sbteclipse/sbteclipse-plugin/scala_2.9.2/sbt_0.12/2.1.1/jars/sbteclipse-plugin.jar
[warn]  [NOT FOUND  ] com.typesafe.sbtidea#sbt-idea;1.1.1!sbt-idea.jar (28ms)
[warn] ==== typesafe-ivy-releases: tried
[warn]   http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/com.typesafe.sbtidea/sbt-idea/scala_2.9.2/sbt_0.12/1.1.1/jars/sbt-idea.jar
[warn]  [NOT FOUND  ] com.typesafe.sbteclipse#sbteclipse-core;2.1.1!sbteclipse-core.jar (31ms)
[warn] ==== typesafe-ivy-releases: tried
[warn]   http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/com.typesafe.sbteclipse/sbteclipse-core/scala_2.9.2/sbt_0.12/2.1.1/jars/sbteclipse-core.jar
[warn]  [NOT FOUND  ] org.scalastyle#scalastyle_2.9.2;0.3.1!scalastyle_2.9.2.jar (0ms)
[warn] ==== sonatype-releasess: tried
[warn]   http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/org/scalastyle/scalastyle_2.9.2/0.3.1/scalastyle_2.9.2-0.3.1.jar
[warn]  [NOT FOUND  ] com.github.scopt#scopt_2.9.2;2.1.0!scopt_2.9.2.jar (0ms)
[warn] ==== sonatype-releasess: tried
[warn]   http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/com/github/scopt/scopt_2.9.2/2.1.0/scopt_2.9.2-2.1.0.jar
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::              FAILED DOWNLOADS            ::
[warn]  :: ^ see resolution messages for details  ^ ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
```

Comment: How does your `plugins.sbt` look like now? Did you change it from the default configuration? Can you include the entire output from `sbt update` in the question?

Comment: Please see EDIT1 in my original post.  I've included both plugin.sbt files.  I also have a Build.scala file in my proj file which adds another resolver, a local maven repo:
  var appResolvers = Seq("my-local-repo" at "http://my.local.domain.net/maven/repo/address/here")

Comment: @JacekLaskowki - any ideas after seeing the full stdout?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the local Play repository as a SBT resolver in plugins.sbt? Try to add following to plugins.sbt:

```
resolvers += Resolver.file("Local Play repo", file(System.getProperty("PLAY_HOME") + "/repositories/local"))(Resolver.ivyStylePatterns)
```

At least you should be able to see it in the list of tried repositories.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but unfortunately it didn't work.  I tried adding this line to both local plugins.sbt as well as the global play one (as well as both)  
So seems that I'm correct in thinking that adding a resolver should result in a `tried` output if jar cannot be found?

Comment: it's not happening.  I even tried removing the resolvers that are defined - no change.  Not sure where to look next.

Comment: @anonymoose Try to create a public GitHub repository so that everybody can download it and build it.

Comment: I'll try to post the project up soon, although there is nothing specific about it.  In the meantime, anyone can easily reproduce this issue by creating a new default play project using `play new` command, then (after disabling access to the typesafe repo) trying a `play clean` on the default project.  The first thing play/sbt tries to do is fetch the sbt-plugin.  And while all other jars are attempted to be fetched from multiple places (I see the _tried_ stdout for each attempt), **the sbt-plugin.jar is only attempted from the typesafe repo.**

Comment: I think I know what's going on - the problem seems to be that the jar's ivy.xml is successfuly fetched but jar itself is blocked for download.  The build downloads the Ivy file first (and this step deems that particular Resolver's step a success, removing the need to try other resolvers), assembles the dep. tree/graph, then goes to fetch the jar itself (address of jar fetch is based orig location of ivy.xml which in this case is typesafe).  I'm assuming that if I block access to the typesafe ivy.xml fetch, the typesafe resolver would fail and the next Res. would attempt to fetch the ivy.xml